# Quarto text justifiction globally

Tags: css, r, quarto, justify

I am intended to do text justification globally in quarto document. I tried the following but it did not work for me:

**style.css**

```
.{
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: Switch `.` to `*`.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful comment. It works like a charm. Please change your comment to answer for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using improper CSS syntax. The symbol to apply styles globally to all elements is `*`, not `.`.